# Как преобразовать дату и время из CSV на графике?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, matplotlib

Имеется файл CSV с данными от некоторых датчиков. В первом столбце имеются данные через одну строку типа: `1550685608, 1550685613, 1550685618` и т.д., то есть дата и время в каком-то зашифрованном виде.

При применении вот этой формулы в соседний столбец `=А1/(3600*24)+ 6/24+25569`, в данном столбце дата и время принимают свой обычный вид. Единственное нужно выставить в формате ячеек нужный формат.

Проблема заключается в том, что не знаю каким образом получить дату и время на графике в *matplotlib*. Точнее, чтобы при загрузке файла и построении графиков, по шкале `х` на протяжении всего графика я видел время. То есть, как сделать это внутри CSV файла я понимаю, а как должен это всё понять питон и как это реализовать не понимаю. Получить график из данных других столбцов я могу, а с этой задачей справиться никак не получается.

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте к вопросу код, который вы уже написали (если есть) и пример данных (можете залить весь файл или его часть на какой-нибудь файлообменник). Тогда другим будет проще вам помочь.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1550685608` - это [UNIX timestamp (AKA epoch)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) - `количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи (00:00:00 UTC) 1 января 1970 года (четверг)`

Парсинг UNIX time в Pandas:

```
In [417]: pd.to_datetime([1550685608, 1550685613, 1550685618], unit='s')
Out[417]: DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-20 18:00:08', '2019-02-20 18:00:13', '2019-02-20 18:00:18'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Пример решения с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')

df.set_index('date').plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример CSV файла:

```
date,sens1,sens2
1550685608,10.2,4.1
1550685613,12.5,2.5
1550685618,9.8,0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fn = r'C:\download\test.csv'
cols = [0,1,3,13]
names=['время','ДУ1','ДУ2','Плотность']

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';', usecols=cols, comment='#', 
                 header=None, names=names)
df['время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['время'], unit='s')
df.set_index('время').plot(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы очень помогли! Забавно что код при том что дополнился, сильно уменьшился в объёме с моим вариантом )

Comment: @АлександрКутыркин, был рад помочь)